# If a f.g. ideal is radical, do the generators generate radical ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and consider a radical ideal $I$ of $k[X_1, ... , X_n]$.  Suppose $I$ is generated by polynomials $f_1, ... , f_t$.  Does it follow that each of the polynomials $f_i$ generates a radical ideal, i.e. is each $f_i$ irreducible?

Now obviously, the answer is **no**, because I can just do some basic ho stuff like: take $n = 1$, let $I = (X)$, then $I$ is a radical ideal, and also $I = (X,X^2)$, but of course $X^2$ isn't irreducible.

But what if I don't allow trivial stuff like that, e.g. assume that $f_i$ is not a member of the ideal $(f_1, ... , f_{i-1}, f_i, ... , f_n)$.

Comment: Radical and irreducible are not interchangeable; consider stuff like $xy$.

Comment: You're right, I should say $f$ generates a radical ideal if and only if it's squarefree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you were told, $f_i$ can generate a radical ideal without being irreducible, so I try to answer the question if $f_i$ should generate a radical ideal if $f_1,\dots,f_t$, $t\ge2$ is a minimal system of generators of a radical ideal $I$. First note that $(f_i)$ is a radical ideal iff $f_i$ has no multiple irreducible factors. Suppose the contrary and write $f_i=g_i^2h_i$ with $g_i$ irreducible. Then $g_i^2h_i^2\in I$, so $g_ih_i\in I$. Now you can replace $f_i$ by $g_ih_i$ in the system of generators, an so on. This shows that you can replace $f_i$ by the product of its irreducible factors, and thus it generates a radical ideal.

Comment: The idea of my answer is that if you have among the generators of a radical ideal one which is not square free (when decompose it into irreducible factors), then this is a "fake" generator and can be replaced by the product of its irreducible factors.